# Ubuntu Upgrade ( Dual Boot with Windows 7)

Tags: ubuntu-10.04

I currently have Ubuntu 10.04 installed alongside windows 7 and would like to uninstall it so i can use 12.04. Having looked on the net it seems as if it is rather complicated to uninstall without encountering anuy issues.

Does anyone know of an Idiot Proof way of uninstalling without breaking my laptop. Im not that technical when it comes to dealing with Operating systems

Thanks

Comment: I think you'd have better luck asking this question in [askubuntu.com](http://www.askubuntu.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/TechnicalOverview/Beta2

There is a section called : Upgrading from Ubuntu 11.10 or Ubuntu 10.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

1. Make backup copy of data you want to save from your existing Ubuntu to the external drive. 2. Prepare new Ubuntu LiveCD.
2. Boot from new LiveCD and install new Ubuntu instead of old one - Ubuntu installer should have such option.
3. Then restore yout data from external drive. This is how I would do this.